# Is there a way to propagate a opentracing context to a go command line tool?

Tags: go, opentracing

I'm trying to propagate a opentracing context to a command line application.
I saw the code for client<->server looks like this:

```
spanCtx, _ := tracer.Extract(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(r.Header))
```

I can't see how to initialize a context object having trace_id and span_id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Tracer interface](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go/blob/bdbb7cc3a1c08db5cc8b3296ec4447544fb43fe3/tracer.go#L7).

1、Use tracer.StartSpan to create a Span.

```
span := tracer.StartSpan("operation1")
```

> how to initialize a context object having trace_id and span_id

Span encapsulates a SpanContext that includes **spanID** and **traceID**.

Check [Span definition](https://opentracing.io/docs/overview/spans/) for more detail.
And here is [Jaeger's implementation of SpanContext](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-go/blob/7aa7af5fd0410a778e14e0a50d062ce4f7cb9e73/span_context.go#L49).

2、Use tracer.Inject to inject the SpanContext for propagation within the carrier, like:

```
carrier := opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(httpReq.Header)
err := tracer.Inject(span.Context(), opentracing.HTTPHeaders, carrier)
```

Then send the carrier to other services, like RPC or HTTP endpoints.

3、In another service, use tracer.Extract to extract the SpanContext:

```
spanCtx, err := tracer.Extract(opentracing.HTTPHeaders, opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(c.Request.Header))
```